# replace css on certain pages by another css

Tags: 6, theming

I use drupal 6. How do I remove global.css from certain path like cart* and replace it with another css? I can add for example stylesheets[all][] = custom.css inside my theme info file but how to load it only on path cart*  and how to disable global.css on the same path? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use your theme to watch for it. You'll need to hook into `preprocess_page` and look for the `global.css` file in the css array and unset it. Below is an example of how to remove the `modules/system/system.css` you'll need to see where in the array `global.css` is and do the same thing. You'll want to wrap that inside of an if for your paths. In this example I use `arg()` to get the first path value (ie cart) and turn it on for that case. You can do what ever you want.

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars)
{
    if(arg(0) == 'cart') {
        $css = $vars['css'];
        unset($css['all']['module']['modules/system/system.css']);
        $vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css($css);
    }
}
```